Why use Gradient Descent in Gradient Boosting algorithm?
Gradient Boosting Algorithm Overview:

Initialization: Start with an initial model. For regression problems, this is often the mean of the target values $(\bar{y})$.
Iteration (Boosting Rounds):
For each iteration $m$, compute residuals from the current model's predictions, i.e., $f_m(x_i)$. That is, compute $r_i=y_i-f_{m}(x_i)$.
Train a new weak learner (e.g., a decision tree) to predict the residuals $r_i(x_i)$.
Update the model's predictions, $f_{m+1}(x)=f_m(x)+\alpha \times newlearner(x)$.

In the above described algorithm, we predict residuals based on $x_i$s. We can show that residuals given in Step 2, is equivalent to negative gradient of a quadratic loss function, and therefore we use negative gradients to train a tree (predict negative gradients from $x$). And therefore, from here comes the name of the method, Gradient Boosting.
Question: We can explicitly compute the residuals $r_i$s without any Gradient Descent algorithm's application, why we complicate the approach and instead directly observable residuals use negative gradients?
